# write table in database with dplyr

Tags: r, postgresql, dplyr

Is there a way to make **dplyr** hooked up to a database pipe data to a new table *within* that database, never downloading the data locally?

I'd like to do something along the lines of:

```
tbl(con, "mytable") %>%
   group_by(dt) %>%
   tally() %>%
   write_to(name = "mytable_2", schema = "transformed")
```

Comment: This reminds me of the time I wrote a Python CGI script that called R that called a database that called a UDF written in R. Why not just write the SQL?

Comment: The **dplyr** syntax is arguably *much* nicer and readable than SQL - especially for when your query would be very long and have subqueries.

Comment: If you're going to be doing this a lot, I'd suggest you bite the bullet and learn SQL. It'll pay off in the long run.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While I whole heartedly agree with the suggestion to learn SQL, you can take advantage of the fact that `dplyr` doesn't pull data until it absolutely has to and build the query using `dplyr`, add the `TO TABLE` clause, and then run the SQL statement using `dplyr::do()`, as in:

```
# CREATE A DATABASE WITH A 'FLIGHTS' TABLE
library(RSQLite)
library(dplyr)
library(nycflights13)
my_db <- src_sqlite("~/my_db.sqlite3", create = T)
flights_sqlite <- copy_to(my_db, flights, temporary = FALSE, indexes = list(
  c("year", "month", "day"), "carrier", "tailnum"))

# BUILD A QUERY
QUERY = filter(flights_sqlite, year == 2013, month == 1, day == 1) %>%
    select( year, month, day, carrier, dep_delay, air_time, distance) %>%
    mutate( speed = distance / air_time * 60) %>%
    arrange( year, month, day, carrier)

# ADD THE "TO TABLE" CLAUSE AND EXECUTE THE QUERY 
do(paste(unclass(QUERY$query$sql), "TO TABLE foo"))
```

You could even write a little functoin that does this:

```
to_table  <- function(qry,tbl)
    dplyr::do(paste(unclass(qry$query$sql), "TO TABLE",tbl))
```

and pipe the query into that function like so:

```
filter(flights_sqlite, year == 2013, month == 1, day == 1) %>%
    select( year, month, day, carrier, dep_delay, air_time, distance) %>%
    mutate( speed = distance / air_time * 60) %>%
    arrange( year, month, day, carrier) %>%
    to_table('foo')
```

Comment: That's basically what `compute()` does

Comment: does not work anymore: `do(paste(unclass(QUERY$query$sql), "TO TABLE foo"))
Error in UseMethod("do_") : 
  no applicable method for 'do_' applied to an object of class "character"`

Comment: @hadley where does `compute()` put the table. I don't see it getting generated in the souce db.schema

Comment: @chrowe It creates it as a temporary table by default

Comment: @hadley is there a way to have it story in a regular table instead?

Comment: @chrowe I was going to say read the docs, but I discovered that I forgot to document those functions  I just added them to the dev version: https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/dev/reference/collapse.tbl_sql.html

Comment: @hadley ok great. that works. So to be clear. This is just executing sql queries, not pulling any data into R?